# Angular2 new keyword within a Pipe

Tags: javascript, angular

I was trying to make a custom pipe in Angular2 to show the age. I can't use here **new Date** because then I'm getting the

**error :Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword**.

How can I solve this ?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'showAge'})
export class AgePipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(bday: Date): Date{
        let today = new Date.now();


        return today-bday;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Date.now`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns a number. If you want to create a `Date` object, remove the `.now`.

```js
console.log(Date.now());
console.log(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

`Date.now()` returns a number, not a constructor.

Perhaps you mean `let today = new Date()` or `let today = Date.now()`?

Answer (score 0):

try using following code for getting today's date

var utc = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10);
document.write(utc);